# jquery traverse parent div to change back ground color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Am new to jquery. I have an html code like the following

```
<div class="left-column">
     <div class="team-logo">
           <img width="72" height="68" src="../public/img/logo/52dce6461dd037.png" alt="Teamlogo">
      </div>
      <div class="team-name">
           test9<br>
           25. January  2014
      </div>
      <div class="team-check">
           <label><input type="checkbox" name="gamecheck[]" value="9"></label>
      </div>
 </div>
```

I have a requirement to change the background color of "left-column" when the check box checked. When its unchecked i have to remove the color.

I have managed to write a code below, but am not getting the parent node "left-column". Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $(this).parent().addClass("redBackground");
    }else{
        $(this).parent().removeClass("redBackground");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.parent()` will only return the element's `immediate parent`. In your current context, You have to use `.closest()` to achieve what do you need.

Try,

```
   $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
       if($(this).is(":checked")) {
          $(this).closest('.left-column').addClass("redBackground");
        }
       else{
           $(this).closest('.left-column').removeClass("redBackground");
         }
     });
```

Answer (score 4):

Target the closest `.left-column` and use `toggleClass` to toggle the class :

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function(){
     $(this).closest('.left-column').toggleClass('redBackground', this.checked);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GpW77/)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy - Not uncommon, someone didn't grokk and a working answer was downvoted, twice. Who cares!

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy - Downvote has become a fashion on stackoverflow now a days. Among 10 question posted on stackoverflow, 6 gets downvoted within 1 minute. Really disgusting.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **parents()** method instead of **parent()** method.

Following code may help you...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){

            $(this).parents('.left-column').addClass("redBackground");
            }else{
            $(this).parents('.left-column').removeClass("redBackground");
            }
            });
});
```

You can  find full working sample from the following link

***[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mhhtarnab/h7LGp/)***